# In watson conversation how to extract multiple values entered in input text

Tags: json, node.js, sails.js, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

Iam working on an application where I display products in my inventory based on the user's "price range"..

I need to know how to extract the values (prices) entered in the input text.

I tried using the system entities @sys-currency & @sys-number but I can extract only one value(the first value)..

example:

the user asks to "display products between $200 and $500"

how can i extract both the values to be compared with the individual products prices and display relevant products..

suggestions appreciated..

Comment: Please share the code that you tried so far, to show us some effort you did before posting the question on SO (you did something right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the node in watson conversation you can access entities as array. In your case it will be:

```
Currency 1: <? entities['sys-currency'] != null && entities['sys-currency'].size()> 0 ? entities['sys-currency'][0].value : "---" ?>; Currency 2: <? entities['sys-currency'] != null && entities['sys-currency'].size()> 1 ? entities['sys-currency'][1].value : "---" ?>
```

You need to add proper null checks and checks if array has more that one entered currency

Answer (score 0):

If you're using nodejs, based on conversation-simple example from IBM Developers, you can do something like:

[image]

And the Node:

[image]

Code for access this values:

```
function updateMessage(input, data, req, res) {

 console.log("Entties: "+JSON.stringify(data.entities));
  //200 and 500 do something
  if (data.entities[0].value == '200' && data.entities[1].value == '500') {
        console.log("User choice value:" + data.entities)
    //  showProducts(data, req, res); do something inside this function
    // or paste your code for do something here
  }
```

Debugg:

[image]

**Obs.:** If the user types only one value (@sys-currency) you'll need to create one if with one condition, and get this value for do something within your application with my example:

```
data.entities //if have one value
data.entities[i] //Watson return some array if have more than 1 value
```

One good idea is use the context variable and join for get all values, like:

```
{ "context": {
    "result": "<? @sys-currency ?>"
   }
},
```

If you passing in the context all items which in stock and you want to have output like We have X,Y,Z in stock, then you can create output in Watson

```
 <? context.results.join(', ') ?> //all values return
```

*Important:* You need to access the `data` return from the *Watson Conversation call* (`conversation.message`) for access all values like entities, intents and context variables, among others. Like:

```
conversation.message(payload, function (err, data) {
    console.log(data)
    if (err) {
      return res.status(err.code || 500).json(err);
    }
}
```